# How to find the number of discordant and concordant pairs in R?

Tags: r, matrix, statistics

I am trying to find the number of discordant and concordant pairs in a clinical trial, and have come across the 'asbio' library which provides the function ConDis.matrix. (http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/asbio/html/ConDis.matrix.html)

The dataset they give as an example is:

```
crab<-data.frame(gill.wt=c(159,179,100,45,384,230,100,320,80,220,320,210),
body.wt=c(14.4,15.2,11.3,2.5,22.7,14.9,1.41,15.81,4.19,15.39,17.25,9.52))
attach(crab)
crabm<-ConDis.matrix(gill.wt,body.wt)
crabm
```

Which gives a result that looks like:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
1  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
2   1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
3   1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
4   1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
5   1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6   1 -1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7   1  1  0 -1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
8   1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
9   1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 NA NA NA NA
10  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 NA NA NA
11  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1 NA NA
12 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA
```

The solution I can think of is adding up the 1s and -1s (for concordant and discordant) respectively but I don't know how to count values in a matrix. Alternatively is someone has a better way of counting concordant/discordant then I would love to know.

Comment: How would your desired output look like?

Comment: I would like a count of concordant and discordant pairs. The overall purpose is to do power calculations to get a sample size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your found solution was

```
sum(crabm == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 57
sum(crabm == -1, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 7
```

You could try (C...concordant, D...discordant pairs):

```
library(DescTools)
tab <- table(crab$gill.wt, crab$body.wt)
ConDisPairs(tab)[c("C","D")]

$C
[1] 57

$D
[1] 7
```